# $\int \frac{x^3}{x^3-a^3} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

I am looking to find out how to integrate $$\int \frac{x^3}{x^3-a^3} \, dx$$

with partial fraction decomposition. 
Could someone take me through the steps? I was recommended to do long division, but somehow I get stuck trying to solve it.

Comment: The division step: $\frac{x^3}{x^3-a^3}=\frac{(x^3-a^3)+a^3}{x^3-a^3}=1+\frac{a^3}{x^3-a^3}$.

Comment: The denominator factorises as $(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)$.

Comment: $1-\dfrac{(ax+a^2)}{x^2+ax+a^2}+\dfrac{ax^2}{x^3-a^3}$

Comment: @HansLundmark I got the same result, but I did not see that I could factor out as Arthur shown, and why cant I just do that straight away instead of doing long division?

Comment: The method for finding the partial fractions decomposition is to make an *Ansatz* according to certain rules (which are explained in every calculus textbook), but this only works if the degree of the numerator is lower than the degree of the denominator, and that's why you have to do long division first if the degree of your numerator is too high.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: taking into account Mann's comment

$$\int\frac{x^3}{x^3-a^3}dx=\int\left(1-\frac a2\frac{2x+a}{x^2+ax+a^2}+\frac{a^2}2\frac1{\left(x+\frac a2\right)^2+\frac34a^2}+\frac a3\frac{3x^2}{x^3-a^3}\right)$$

The first, second and fourth terms' integrals above are immediate, taking into account that

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log f(x)+K$$

As for the third one:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac a2\right)^2+\frac34a^2}=\frac4{3a^2}\int\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac{2x+a}{\sqrt3\,a}\right)^2}=\frac2{\sqrt3\,a}\int\frac{\frac2{\sqrt3\,a}dx}{1+\left(\frac{2x+a}{\sqrt3\,a}\right)^2}$$

Now use (after understanding/proving/justifying)

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}dx=\arctan f(x)+C$$